# Spring JPA findBy mehod returns duplicate values

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring JPA for Mysql in my application and I have method like below in repository.

I'm getting duplicate values, 2 times in the list.

```
public interface repository  extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
 List<User> findByUserId(String userId)
}
```

Comment: Are you getting same `User` two or more times or are you getting many `User`s with same `userId`? Put some examples.

Comment: UserId isnt your PK - so it seems entirely possible - run select * from User where user_id = '' in your db to test

Comment: Kindly tag your question as `spring-data-jpa` rather than `jpa`. It is not using the JPA API there, that is the "Spring Data JPA" API ... different thing

Comment: Hi, this issue was fixed. I have added unique key constraint in mysql db.